# Shutdown hangs on "A stop job is running to for Mysql Community Server"

Tags: 16.04, mysql, shutdown

I'm using MySQL ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17 for Linux (x86_64) on Ubuntu 16.04. Whenever I shutdown Ubuntu, it hangs here.

[image]

After 10 minutes, it automatically kills the process (my guess). I ran into this problem many times. I did a clean install a few times, it works for a while, but then starts doing the same thing after a few proper shutdowns.

Pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del 7 times consecutively forces a shutdown. Forcing a shutdown like this corrupted my MySQL data. Has anyone else ran into this problem?

Comment: What happens when you run `sudo service mysql stop` on the command line? Maybe some script needs some intervention when shutting down the MySQL server.

Comment: [enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615129/systemd-mysql-wont-stop)
it work for me

Answer (score 8):

Thats because you got problems with timezone settings:

> Got the same issue, found a possible explanation: my cloud provider store time in local timezone (earlier than UTC); at startup MySQL boot first, then NTP, which updates the time to UTC; therefore, MySQL literally "started in the future" (sounds interesting).

Running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` should do the trick

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1600164/comments/11

Comment: it looks like it doesn't have to be a cloud provider.  In our situation, just having the BIOS time set in the future, then installing and running MySQL, then setting the time correctly will also cause the problem.  This is on a machine completely disconnected from the network and ntp disbaled.

Answer (score 4):

Before shutting down your system, try running this to manually shut down the mysql service.

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Alternatively, write a script to automate the process:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Make sure to mark it as executable. Presuming you saved it as a file named `shutdown`, run this command:

```
chmod u+x shutdown
```

Now you can execute your script.

```
./shutdown
```

Comment: If MySql server hangs on shutdown, it will also hang on `service mysql stop` command. Right approach here is to investigate why MySql server hangs.

Answer (score 2):

Strangely enough, this worked for me:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

possible explanation: my cloud provider store time in local timezone (earlier than UTC); at startup MySQL boot first, then NTP, which updates the time to UTC; therefore, MySQL literally 'started in the future'

Answer (score 0):

Shut down the pc using command- sudo init 0
Though this sounds stupid but yes, it works. It worked for me and even for you too. Actually the server does not stopped because of not being getting the super administrative privileges. So next time shut down using this command.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone else, this is what has resolved the issue for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Basically delayed the service startup in the mysql.service file under /lib/systemd/system/
I added 
`After=lightdm.service` and `wants=lightdm.service`.
(My lightdm.service is itself delayed until domain authentication has taken place)
I guess you could use any other service that you know will start later on in the boot. These service files will also shutdown the services when Ubuntu is shutdown in the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running `sudo apt-get install mysql*`, and after the installation finished everything seems to be working nice and easy now... Both following the user680697's nice idea and also shutting down or restarting using GUI capabilities(I'm on Ubuntu Mate 16.04).

Answer (score 0):

Install `mysql-client` with

```
apt-get install mysql-client
```

That should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug in MySQL.

Please see Bug Report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93708

To solve this issue, just update your MySQL since the fix is in this update ->

> [27 May 2019 13:25] Daniel Price
> Fixed as of the upcoming 5.7.27, 8.0.17 release, and here's the changelog entry:
>
> Manually changing the system time while the MySQL server was running
> caused page cleaner thread delays.

credits to Daniel Price.

Answer (score -1):

This happens to me to when I changed the hostname with :

`$ sudo hostnamectl set-hostname my-new-hostname`

without stopping the mysql server.