# How to remove stop-jobs?

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, systemd, services, mssql

I have installed Microsoft SQL-Server on my ubuntu machine. 
Now it works fine, but every time I shutdown the machine, shutdown halts at

```
A stop job is running for microsoft sql server database engine ( x/30min )
```

Now if you wait 30 minutes, then it shuts off, so technically, it's not a bug. 
However, when I have to shut off the laptop I don't have time to wait 30 minutes ...
Also, I sometimes have to restart the machine, and don't want to have to wait 30 minutes to restart it...

Is there any way to block or disable this stop-job?
Where are stop-jobs configured?

Comment: Are you sure this is not a timezone problem? I seem to remember seeing this for mysql once. -- *yay* for my memory: https://askubuntu.com/questions/892026/shutdown-hangs-on-a-stop-job-is-running-to-for-mysql-community-server  :)

Comment: @Rinzwind: So you're suggesting this is a service-boot-order-problem ? sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`, but that didn't help. 
What helps is the following:

Open `/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service` with a text-editor 
and change `TimeoutSec=30min` to `TimeoutSec=5sec`

Then run

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

to reload the configuration.

That's it, the timeout is now 5 seconds instead of 30 minutes.

> For risks and side effects, read the package leaflet and ask
>   your doctor or pharmacist - and keep a backup handy at all times.
>   You should do that anyway.

For more information: [RTFM](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files) / [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)

**Note:**
As per PerlDuck's tipp, instead of directly editing `/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service`, you should `sudo systemctl edit mssql-server.service` to create a drop-in that does not get overwritten when mssql is updated.

The file 
/etc/systemd/system/mssql-server.service.d/override.conf
should only contain the values it overrides, e.g.

```
[Service]
TimeoutSec=5sec
```

Comment: I would suggest you use 5 minutes instead of 5 seconds becuase MSSQL Server will get straight killed after 5 seconds and that could cause some nasty evil with MSSQL in the long run.

Comment: @Thomas Ward: That already happened once before - master database file gone. apt-get remove --purge and reinstall with restore db from backup helped. Seriously, MS should apply the google rule: if it takes longer than 4 seconds, it's a bug. No rule without exception.

Comment: Yes, but if MSSQL doesn't want to stop in the first place, then this won't matter.

Comment: @The MATE Man: Yep, agree. It will be killed either way.

Comment: Honestly, I just try stay away from Microsoft software because I've had little, annoying problems like this in the past with Microsoft software running on Linux.

Comment: @The MATE Man: I've actually switched to Linux entirely, privately. But at work, we're using MS. I work an hour or two per day on the private laptop while on train - counts as work-time. But I need ms-sql for that, unfortunately. For private things, I use pg anyway, so much nicer with array parameters and gis. ;) I presume their database running on a linux-laptop is what ms considers an edge-case anyway.

Comment: Instead of directly editing `/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service` you should `sudo systemctl edit mssql-server.service` to create a drop-in that does not get overwritten when mssql is updated.