# MySQL won't stop on shut down

Tags: mysql, shutdown, 17.04

When I shut down my system, there is a message on the log:

```
A stop job is running for MySQL Community Server (xs / 10min)
```

I'm able to quit using MagicSysRq keys, but it doesn't seem the proper way to do this.

This is happening 60% of the time.

I Googled the issue, and I found this question: [Systemd Mysql won't stop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615129/systemd-mysql-wont-stop). I implemented [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/624673) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/712367), but the issue still persists.

Can somebody suggest a solution?

I'm currently using Ubuntu 17.04, and MySQL v. 14.14.

Comment: Did you try the other suggestions on that page?

Comment: No, and if fact, one of them is solved my problem. I flagged my question as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem, how it's written [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/874761/297406).

I created a service which start mysql service with delay.

However it is very important to note, that before reinstalling MySql you should disable delay_mysql.service, otherwise you got an error.